# Programs to draw human face

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm working on a project that needs to draw pictures of human lips. 
I just wonder if there is a program to draw a human face (or simply lips).

Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? How realistic do you want it to be? In what style? What are some end results that you are looking to create?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at some of the human character creating suites which all have more or less elaborate human face rendering capabilities including mouth, and lips.

- [Make Human](http://www.makehuman.org/) young, quite capable free and Open Source project but with still limited external content libraries.
- [DAZ Studio](http://www.daz3d.com/products) free but closed source human modelling and rendering software offering many paid additions.
- [Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com) paid software but it is the classic human modeller which changed owners a lot in the past.